# Django - getting hostname error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get name of the client that is trying to connect to server via Django, and I am stuck on this:

views.py

```
def home(request):
    ime = request.META('REMOTE_HOST')
    return HttpResponse('Welcome, %s.' %ime)
```

and error is:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable

**Traceback**
8. ime = request.META('REMOTE_HOST')
```

So, I don't get what the problem is.
I am still learning Django, btw.

Comment: The "name of the client" would be the ip?

Comment: No, that would be machine's name.

Answer (score 0):

`request.META` is a dictionary, so you need to access the `REMOTE_HOST` value with its key.

Change to:

```
ime = request.META['REMOTE_HOST'] # Note brackets not parens
```

Comment: Hmmmm, that's right. It works, but now I am having another problem.
I am getting empty answer. It's returning me:

          Welcome, .

Comment: You're missing a space in your string formatting. Try this: `return HttpResponse('Welcome, %s.' % ime)`

Comment: Then you've got a problem with your `ime` and thus your REMOTE_HOST value.